# Cakephp 2.4.2 : Route URL

Tags: cakephp, routes

I have to do route for following urls. I have gone through book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html and googled it and but didn't find any solution for me.

```
http://example.com/Homes/Browse/12
http://example.com/Homes/Browse/13
http://example.com/Homes/Browse/14
http://example.com/Homes/Browse/15
http://example.com/Homes/Browse/16
http://example.com/Homes/Browse/17
http://example.com/Homes/Browse/18
and so on..
```

I want the output like this for all urls mentioned above.

OUTPUT: http://example.com/Homes

I tried these both codes but doesn't work for me.

```
Router::connect('/Homes/*', array('controller' => 'Homes', 'action' => 'Browse'));

Router::connect('/Homes/*', array('controller' => 'Homes', 'action' => 'Browse','[0-9]+'));
```

Comment: how about use small caps for the array `'controller' => 'homes'` and small caps `'action' => 'browse'`

Comment: The first thing I do find when googling for "cakephp routes" are the docs. Looking at your code, you don't seem to have read them? **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html** And on a side note, "_doesn't work_" is a not a proper problem description! Also you should always mention the exact CakePHP version that you are using.

Comment: @dhidy: I tried it. But it does not work

Comment: @ndm: I have already read. Thats why I was asking for solution. Mentioned the version 2.4.2

Comment: Well, then you didn't pay enough attention, nowhere does it mention that regex patterns are supposed to go into the URL array. And again, "_doesn't work_" is _not_ a useful problem description, please properly describe your actual problem! Your question is pretty confusing, you kinda say you want URLs like `http://example.com/Homes/Browse/12`, and in the next sentence you're just dumping "_OUTPUT: `http://example.com/Homes`_"... what does that even mean? Is that what you want? Is that what you get? Are you talking about generating URLs with a helper? ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> Router::connect('/Homes', array('controller' => 'Homes', 'action' => 'Browse'));

Comment: Tried, but does not work for each and every url  http://example.com/Homes/Browse/12, http://example.com/Homes/Browse/13, http://example.com/Homes/Browse/14 and so on

Comment: Are you using Html Helper to create your urls. Html Helper will change url automatically if url is passed as arguments with array('controller' => 'Homes', 'action' => 'Browse' , 12)

Comment: Yes I used this==> array('controller' => 'Homes', 'action' => 'Browse' , 12) . But this will only work for 12, I want to use it for all numbers. Is it possible?